# How to create a 3D curved surface, given some discrete points in space?

Tags: plotting

I have  some 3D point data and I want to create a curved surface with these points, and export the curved surface data (point coordinates) according to points density on the curved surface. How can I do that?

The data is in 3 columns. I use `ListPlotPoint3D[]` to show the spatial distribution of these points.

```
w1 = Import["FaultMode_szk_test.txt", "Table"];

104.0152    31.3715 -1.8614
103.9882    31.3934 -4.7228
103.9611    31.4154 -6.5841
103.9341    31.4373 -8.4455
103.9070    31.4592 -9.3069 
103.9591    31.3203 -1.8614 
103.9318    31.3420 -4.7228
103.9045    31.3637 -6.5841
103.8772    31.3854 -8.4455 
103.8498    31.4071 -9.3069 
103.9035    31.2694 -1.8614 
103.8762    31.2910 -4.7228 
103.8490    31.3127 -6.5841 
103.8217    31.3344 -8.4455 
103.7944    31.3561 -9.3069 
103.8480    31.2184 -1.8614 
103.8207    31.2401 -4.7228 
103.7932    31.2616 -6.9841 
103.7735    31.2925 -8.6455 
103.7475    31.3150 -9.3069 
103.8003    31.1799 -1.8614 
103.7825    31.2073 -3.7228 
103.7662    31.2350 -5.5841 
103.7285    31.2631 -7.4455    
103.7079    31.2891 -9.3069

ListPointPlot3D[w1]
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `ListPlot3D`.

```
data = {{104.0152`, 31.3715`, -1.8614`}, {103.9882`, 
    31.3934`, -4.7228`}, {103.9611`, 31.4154`, -6.5841`}, {103.9341`, 
    31.4373`, -8.4455`}, {103.907`, 31.4592`, -9.3069`}, {103.9591`, 
    31.3203`, -1.8614`}, {103.9318`, 31.342`, -4.7228`}, {103.9045`, 
    31.3637`, -6.5841`}, {103.8772`, 31.3854`, -8.4455`}, {103.8498`, 
    31.4071`, -9.3069`}, {103.9035`, 31.2694`, -1.8614`}, {103.8762`, 
    31.291`, -4.7228`}, {103.849`, 31.3127`, -6.5841`}, {103.8217`, 
    31.3344`, -8.4455`}, {103.7944`, 31.3561`, -9.3069`}, {103.848`, 
    31.2184`, -1.8614`}, {103.8207`, 31.2401`, -4.7228`}, {103.7932`, 
    31.2616`, -6.9841`}, {103.7735`, 31.2925`, -8.6455`}, {103.7475`, 
    31.315`, -9.3069`}, {103.8003`, 31.1799`, -1.8614`}, {103.7825`, 
    31.2073`, -3.7228`}, {103.7662`, 31.235`, -5.5841`}, {103.7285`, 
    31.2631`, -7.4455`}, {103.7079`, 31.2891`, -9.3069`}};

ListPlot3D[data]
```

This will only work if the surface "does not curve under itself", i.e. it could be described by a $z=f(x,y)$ function.

Comment: ,Thanks to you ,How can I get the z=f(x,y) ?

Answer (score 1):

You can get a function for your data using interpolation. First reformat Szabolcs variable `data` into `data2' and create a function`f`

```
 data2 = Table[{data[[i, {1, 2}]], data[[i, 3]]}, {i, 1, Length[data]}]; 
 f = Interpolation[data2, InterpolationOrder -> 1]
```

You can plot the function

```
 {minx, maxx} = {Min[data[[All, 1]]], Max[data[[All, 1]]]};
 {miny, maxy} = {Min[data[[All, 2]]], Max[data[[All, 2]]]};
 Plot3D[f[x, y], {x, minx, maxx}, {y, miny, maxy}]
```

or ask for the value of the function at any point:

```
f[104,31.4]
```

and get an answer (1.68 in this case) even though the "data" does not exist at that point. Observe that Mathematica may give you a warning when you ask for values that are outside the known range of the function.

Comment: I get an error: `Interpolation::indim: The coordinates do not lie on a structured tensor product grid. >>` Version difference perhaps?  Nevertheless you could write:  `data2 = {{#, #2}, #3} & @@@ data;` and `{{minx, maxx}, {miny, maxy}} = {Min@#, Max@#} & /@ Most@Transpose@data;` to simplify your answer.

Comment: I think they updated Interpolation to work with unstructured grids at some point. Version 9 has this, but insists that it can only use InterpolationOrder->1 (which is why I added that optino to remove the warning).